# How to capture audio in an xvfb system using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, xvfb

Want to capture the audio using ffmpeg 
Went to this [link](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop)

The error coming on the first one is

```
ffmpeg exited with code 1: hw:0: Input/output error
```

And the pulse one is running on my laptop but not on the server i think some missing drivers

```
ffmpeg exited with code 1: default: No such process
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PulseAudio](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/) was missing. Did

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
```

and followed the second command below, and it works fine.

```
ffmpeg -video_size 1024x768 -framerate 25 -f x11grab -i :0.0+100,200 -f alsa -ac 2 -i hw:0 output.mkv
```